# Interference of light in a dielectric mirror

Tags: optics, interference

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror/) it is mentioned that for dielectric mirrors (mirrors designed to reflect a specific wavelength of light) "there is a 180-degree difference in phase shift at a low-to-high index boundary, compared to a high-to-low index boundary, which means that these reflections are also in phase" and therefore the reflections will interfere constructively. How is this the case - I thought that a 180˚ difference in phase shift meant the waves were actually antiphase and should interfere destructively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full sentence from that [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror):

> The reflections from the low-index layers have exactly half a
>   wavelength in path length difference, but there is a 180-degree
>   difference in phase shift at a low-to-high index boundary, compared to
>   a high-to-low index boundary, which means that these reflections are
>   also in phase.

Observe that there are two effects going on:

1. The path length difference is one-half wavelength (180 degrees)
2. The phase shift at the boundary is different by 180 degrees.

These two effects add to produce a 360 degree (full wave) shift.  That is why the reflections are *in phase*.

This can all be [visualized](http://www.olympusmicro.com/primer/lightandcolor/mirrorsintro.html) as:

[image]

Each layer is a quarter-wavelength.  That means that a round-trip through the layer is a half-wavelength (180 degrees).  This phase shift added to the different phase shift due to reflection at the high-to-low and low-to-high index boundaries explains why the reflections are in phase.